# Select system function names in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a bunch of queries.

What I have to do is selecting records which has query using SQL Server system function.

It would be the best to select all system function names so that I can get it done with the subquery within a where clause.

The advice would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recommended that you use the system functions, Information Schema Views, or the system stored procedures to obtain system information without directly querying the system tables.
Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191238%28v=sql.90%29.aspx